unable to start container process: exec: "npm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
I've created a Dockerfile that creates a react project taking Ubuntu image as base, and on running the container it gives this error
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "npm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

Here's the Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt update &&\
    apt-get -y install curl &&\
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash &&\
    export NVM_DIR="/root/.nvm" &&\
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" &&\
    nvm install --lts &&\
    npm create vite@latest -y . -- --template react-ts &&\
    npm install

EXPOSE 5173
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
CMD ["--", "--host"]

I tried adding npm & node executable files to path variable, but it doesn't seems to be working.

Version managers like nvm don't work well in Docker.  On the other hand, your image contains a single application that uses a single Node version.  Can you start your Dockerfile FROM node:lts instead?  How to install nvm in docker? talks through some of the mechanics, but it shouldn't be necessary.

How about simply starting from the node:latest image?
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm create vite@latest -y . -- --template react-ts && \
    npm install

EXPOSE 5173
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
CMD ["--", "--host"]

Equally, as suggested by David Maze in the comments, start from node:lts.

